# How to select most frequent name from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with lot of names like this:

```
  MrMiroBear
  MrMiroBear
  BigBear
  MrMiroBear
  BigBear
  MrMiroBear
  MrMiroBear
  BigBear
  MrMiroBear
  MrMiroBear
  BigBear
  MrMiroBear
  BigBear
  BigBear
  MrMiroBear
  BigBear
  BigBear
  MrMiroBear
  BigBear
```

How do I select the most name frequent name in this table?
I only need the name, not the count.

I've tried this query but it gives me only count of name, not name

```
select Top 1 Count(*) as TopName From _Client group by ClientName
```

Comment: If your query works you are not using MySQL.

Comment: `TOP 1` is SQL-Server, not MySQL. Please use correct tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query works, you are not using MySQL.

The answer to your question would then be:

```
select Top 1 ClientName
From _Client
group by ClientName
order by count(*) desc;
```

In other words, you have to select the field that you want.

Note:  There could be ties.  If you want all top client names:

```
select Top (1) With Ties ClientName
From _Client
group by ClientName
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select ClientName 
From _Client 
group by ClientName
order by count(*) desc
limit 1`

Comment: i got error after Limit 1 "Incorrect syntax near 'limit'."

Answer (score 0):

Just add ClientName to the output and order by the count descending

```
select Top 1 ClientName TopName
From _Client 
group by ClientName
order by Count(*)  desc
```

or, for mySQL,

```
select ClientName TopName 
From _Client 
group by ClientName
order by Count(*)  desc
Limit 1
```

Comment: i got Name and count i need only name

Comment: Well take the count out then

Answer (score 0):

select Top 1 ClientName as frequent name From _Client
group by ClientName order by count(*) desc;